# SQL - Get the last entries without 'order by'

Tags: sql

I have a problem with a sql-query for my database. I want to get the last n-entries of a specific Table. Usually I would perform the following query: 'Select Top 1000 (*) FROM Table ORDER BY Column DESC', but the problem is, that the table contains a lot of data and always ends up in a timeout because of the order process and even if the timeout wouldn't occur, I just can't tolerate the delay in my application.

So what I am looking for is a way to get the last entries without re-ordering the table! 
Am I just indulge in wishful thinking, or is there a way to get this done?

Comment: what do you mean with "last entries"?

Comment: is your order column indexed?

Comment: Have you added an index on Column? that should speed up the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this. Relational databases are not required to keep their rows in any particular order... So, there's no way of knowing which row is physically stored last. You'll need to use the `ORDER BY.` Sorry about that...

You might be able to improve performance with some appropriate indexes, though. This sort of thing should be pretty fast with an index.

Comment: +1 Agreed. If the database isn't able to return it's dataset in reasonable manner, there's something terribly wrong usually.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with searching within the MESSAGE Field of a huge log4net log table.

Fortunately the LOG table has a timestamp field so I was able to speedup the query by adding add additional filter conditions and indexes.

```
SELECT top 1000 * FROM table WHERE time_stamp >= today

or 

SELECT top 1000 * FROM table WHERE id > first_id_today
```

Additional: avoid using (*) especially if you have binariy fields in your table!